# How to transpose data in pandas Dataframe by reading one row at a time?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multiple-columns, transpose

In the pandas dataframe:

```
contig  haplotype_block hap_X   hap_Y   odds_ratio  My_hap  Sp_hap
2         726           C-G-C   T-C-T    0.012      C-G-C    T-C-T
2         1094          G-C     A-T      0.02       A-T      G-C
2         1335          C-T-T   A-C-A    0.001      A-C-A    C-T-T
2         3353          T-T     A-C      314.5      T-T      A-C
```

I want to transpose the data. A simple transpose would have worked but this is a little complicated.

- I don't need to move the column-index.
- Basically the number of rows will increase.

All, I want to do is read each line (row and then) transpose that line first.

```
contig  haplotype_block hap_X   hap_Y   odds_ratio  My_hap  Sp_hap
2         726           C       T        0.012      C         T
2         726           G       C         -         G         C
2         726           C       T         -         C         T
2         1094          G       A        0.02       A         G
2         1094          C       T         -         T         C
```

Now, transpose 3rd line and add to the above dataframe along the rows.

I can do it using for-loop (reading each line at a time) but I am specifically looking for solutions using pandas dataframe, so the memory footprint as well the code comprehension is clear and elegant.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
from  itertools import chain

#create list by split
cols = ['hap_X','hap_Y','My_hap','Sp_hap']
df[cols] = df[cols].apply(lambda x: x.str.split('-'))

#new df with flatening lists and repeating
lens = df.hap_X.str.len()
df2 = pd.DataFrame({
        "contig": np.repeat(df.contig.values, lens),
        "haplotype_block": np.repeat(df.haplotype_block.values, lens),
        "hap_X": list(chain.from_iterable(df.hap_X)),
        "hap_Y": list(chain.from_iterable(df.hap_Y)),
        "odds_ratio": np.repeat(df.odds_ratio.values, lens),
        "My_hap": list(chain.from_iterable(df.My_hap)),
        "Sp_hap": list(chain.from_iterable(df.Sp_hap))
}).reindex_axis(df.columns, axis=1)

#correct column odds_ratio - only first value
s = pd.Series(np.repeat(df.index.values, lens))
df2.loc[s.duplicated(), 'odds_ratio'] = '-'
print (df2)

   contig  haplotype_block hap_X hap_Y odds_ratio My_hap Sp_hap
0       2              726     C     T      0.012      C      T
1       2              726     G     C          -      G      C
2       2              726     C     T          -      C      T
3       2             1094     G     A       0.02      A      G
4       2             1094     C     T          -      T      C
5       2             1335     C     A      0.001      A      C
6       2             1335     T     C          -      C      T
7       2             1335     T     A          -      A      T
8       2             3353     T     A      314.5      T      A
9       2             3353     T     C          -      T      C
```